# python-docx: Insert a paragraph after

Tags: python, python-docx

In python-docx, the `paragraph` object has a method [insert_paragraph_before](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.insert_paragraph_before) that allows inserting text before itself:

```
p.insert_paragraph_before("This is a text")
```

There is no `insert_paragraph_after` method, but I suppose that a paragraph object knows sufficiently about itself to determine which paragraph is next in the list. Unfortunately, the inner workings of the python-docx AST are a little intricate (and not really documented).

I wonder how to program a function with the following spec?

```
def insert_paragraph_after(para, text):
```

Answer (score 8):

Trying to make sense of the inner workings of docx made me dizzy, but fortunately, it's easy enough to accomplish what you want, since the internal object already has the necessairy method `addnext`, which is all we need:

```
from docx import Document

from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement

def insert_paragraph_after(paragraph, text=None, style=None):
    """Insert a new paragraph after the given paragraph."""
    new_p = OxmlElement("w:p")
    paragraph._p.addnext(new_p)
    new_para = Paragraph(new_p, paragraph._parent)
    if text:
        new_para.add_run(text)
    if style is not None:
        new_para.style = style
    return new_para

def main():
    # Create a minimal document
    document = Document()
    p1 = document.add_paragraph("First Paragraph.")
    p2 = document.add_paragraph("Second Paragraph.")

    # Insert a paragraph wedged between p1 and p2
    insert_paragraph_after(p1, "Paragraph One And A Half.")

    # Test if the function succeeded
    document.save(r"D:\somepath\docx_para_after.docx")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Comment: How to add paragraph_after_ a list of words ? List = {"Dog", "Cat","Pig", "Parrot"} Note:- Words must be removed after adding paragraph ?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand your question: your “list” isn’t part of a docx document structure, it’s just an ordinary Python set (not a list, btw). You would first have to somehow convert this set into a part of a docx document. You could also increase your chances of getting an answer if you don’t hide your question in the comment for another four year old question.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below details:

```
para1 = document.add_paragraph("Hello World")
para2 = document.add_paragraph("Testing!!")

p1 = para1._p
p1.addnext(para2._p)
```

[Reference](https://www.yeahshecodes.com/python/using-python-docx-create-word-documents)

Comment: nice and succinct!

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time I found another method, more high level (though *perhaps* not as elegant). It essentially finds the parent, lists the children, works out its own position in line and then gets the next one.

```
def par_index(paragraph):
    "Get the index of the paragraph in the document"
    doc = paragraph._parent
    # the paragraphs elements are being generated on the fly,
    # they change all the time
    # so in order to index, we must use the elements
    l_elements = [p._element for p in doc.paragraphs]
    return l_elements.index(paragraph._element)


def insert_paragraph_after(paragraph, text, style=None):
    """
    Add a paragraph to a docx document, after this one.
    """
    doc = paragraph._parent
    i = par_index(paragraph) + 1 # next
    if i <= len(doc.paragraphs):
        # we find the next paragraph and we insert before:
        next_par = doc.paragraphs[i]
        new_par = next_par.insert_paragraph_before(text, style)
    else:
        # we reached the end, so we need to create a new one:
        new_par = parent.add_paragraph(text, style)
    return new_par
```

One advantage is that it mostly avoids getting into the inner workings.

Comment: Slight nitpick: since this solution uses the attribut `_element`, it still uses the hidden, dangerous inner workings.

Comment: That feels a little doctrinarian... Note that I myself praised the other solution and (disclosure) I gave it a + point after this answer had received one, in order to balance things. Sometimes, fairness and cooperation achieve more than competition.

Comment: That's why I prefaced my remark with "slight nitpick". I didn't downvote your answer -- in fact, I just upvoted it, to clarify that I think it's a perfectly valid one. There is a risk that `_element` (or its synonym `_p`) might vanish with the next version of docx, but that risk is very theoretical, I think. In any case, wether you pick my answer or your own for production, you should protect it with a unittest, but I guess you know that already.